How should I fill a gap along a sidewalk after removing edging?
We removed a concrete over stone edge that was cracked along the length of my property. Formerly, it separated the yard from the sidewalk. We considered replacing it with something like Belgium block, but most of the houses in our neighborhood simply transition from grass to the sidewalk without any kind of border. Is there a good way to fill in the 2-3 inch gap below grade and slope the dirt to the sidewalk? Would this be a good application for sod or try to seed it? Just looking for some expertise - everything online is about how to add a border, but not much about removing one to grass.


Why did you remove the border without a plan for when it was gone?  Now if someone breaks an ankle from stepping off the sidewalk it's your fault.

Depends on your budget. Sod would be fantastic here. In either case, the first step is to fill with good black soil, either to flush with the sidewalk or to about an inch down. Compact it well to avoid undue settling later.
Then either sprinkle on some seed and rake it in a bit, or cut sod to fit and press it in. Neither approach is difficult.
Check out the Gardening Stack for further advice.

The difficult part is watering consistently enough to get the grass to take. It's still early enough in the season for most of the US that either approach is feasible, just water it well.

@FredricShope since it's linear, this looks like a perfect application for one of those irrigation hoses that weeps water along its entire length.

Sort of. I wouldn't want a hose laying muddy in my newly set seed. A spritz a day does the trick, or twice if it's very hot.
